# New column Variable for a Series in python

Tags: python, series

I am trying to categorize my data in pd.Series using the following code:

```
for index in range (len(B)):
    if B.loc[index, 'N1', 'N4']:
        B['Category'] = NN1
       
    elif B.loc[index, 'N2', 'N3','N5']:
        B['Category']== NN2

    else return(nan)
```

There is no pattern to be followed because I have already pre-processed the data and found out that N1 and N4 falls in NN1 category. The same goes to N2, N3 and N5 which all falls to the NN2 Category.

B is my data Series.
N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 are my row indices.
'Category' is the new column that I wanted to add in my Series.

Using the above code mentioned, my error is this:

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>
```

Anyone who could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code - firstly, you address the index as an integer even though you have a non-numerical index. Secondly, what you intend as your second assignment is really a boolean expression. The return statement makes sense only in a function body, but the rows that do not get an explicit assignment in the `Category` column, will be assigned `nan` anyway. Since you need more than one column, work with a DataFrame, not a Series. If you receive a Series `S` from somewhere else, you can create a DataFrame from it by e.g.

```
B = pd.DataFrame(S, index=S.index).
```

With B, you could then do something like this

```
for index in B.index:
    if index in {'N1', 'N4'}:
        B.loc[index, 'Category'] = 'NN1'
    elif index in {'N2', 'N3', 'N5'}:
        B.loc[index, 'Category'] = 'NN2'
```

or rather

```
for index in ['N1', 'N4']:
    B.loc[index, 'Category'] = 'NN1'
for index in ['N2', 'N3', 'N5']:
    B.loc[index, 'Category'] = 'NN2'
```

Comment: Thank yo so much. I used the latter and it worked!:)